# How can i load the CSS before the Laravel code? Using Tailwind

Tags: html, css, laravel

My problem: When i go to my page, the first look is the HTML code without the style but 1 second later this is loaded. How can i solve this? I need to make the CSS load before to see the web site always with the style even if i go to other links/routes, you know.

I'm using Laravel, templates, html code and TailwindCSS

Thank you.

Comment: Whenever I've run into this in the past, the culprit has always been slow/poorly optimized JS.  In those cases adding `defer` to the script tag has a positive effect.  Your case might be more complicated, but you cannot make the CSS load before "laravel" as the HTML/CSS/JS doesn't load until the back end (laravel) has finished.

Comment: Already solved. The problem was that i was charging 2 templates on the same blade.php

Answer (score 0):

I never used Laravel but you can try calling the tailwinds library before Laravel.

`<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the top of `<head>` so tailwind loads before anything else.